# Override whiplash exitstatus from msgbox

Tags: linux, bash, whiptail

Is it possible to override the exitstatus from a [whiptail](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whiptail) `msgbox` ?  By default, hitting the OK button exists the whiptail application.  Ideally, I'd like to end up back on my main menu page, since that is the focal point of my app:

```
#! /bin/bash

OPTION=$(whiptail --title "Configuration Menu" --menu "Choose an option" 40 78 30 \ "1"     "Return to main menu." \ "2"     "Show current configuration." \ "3"     "Enter Neo Serial Number." \ "4"     "Change Neo IP Address." \ "5"     "Change Neo Gateway."  3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)

exitstatus=$?

case "$OPTION" in   2)
    whiptail  --title "Current Configuration" --msgbox "Your current Neo configuration \n
        IP Address:  `ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'` \n
        Gateway: `ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'` \n
        DNS Server(s): `ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | g$
    ;; esac
```

> The main menu...

[image: The main menu]

> Option 2 menu...

[image: Option 2 menu]

Hitting 'OK' at this point completely exists my app.  Instead, I'd like it to exit back to the main menu.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was much easier than expected, just wrapped in a while loop:

```
 while true
 do
  .....
 done
```